# Node.js Express post method is not recognised by WebStorm 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webstorm

I'm new to node.js and I decided to try out express module on my application. Everything was ok until I tried to use app.post method.
I'm writting my app on WebStorm 6.0.2 and it does't recognise it:
"Unresolved function or method post()" - is what I get.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.post('/', function(req, res) {});
```

However with get method everything is ok:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('hello world');
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when you launch your node app?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck No, it gives no errors.

Comment: use VScode  it is the best editor , install auto complete plugins for node and express js.

Comment: @volk please mark as answer me because is reputation more than another

Comment: @MostafaMashayekhi You've answered after 4 years of the initial question, 4 major versions of Webstorm was released.

At the time the question was answered the first answer satisfied my needs, whereas yours - did not (I had TypeScript community tabs installed at the time of asking)

I'm glad that 9 people found your comment useful, but it didn't help me with my particular problem, so I'll leave the first comment marked as an answer.

Get in touch if you have any objections and thanks for understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

known issue. The problem is that express modules are defined in rather weird way - see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6667#comment=27-470393 for details/possible workaround

Answer (score 10):

Open Settings | JavaScript | Libraries
 click "Download"
 select "TypeScript community stubs"
 select express.js and click "Download and Install".